# Insert data into database from input in python using sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-insert

Let's assume I have the following table in a database called `data.db`:

```
CREATE TABLE species 
(
    species_id int PRIMARY KEY,    -- NCBI taxonomic code
    abbrev character(2),
    latin  character varying(50),
    common character varying(20)
);
```

How can I manually add new data into this database from Python using SQL?

The input function should look something like this:

```
Please define a 'species_id', that should be inserted to the database: 
Please define a 'latin', that should be inserted to the database: 
Please define a 'abbrev' that should be inserted to the database:
```

The code I have tried looks like this:

```
def data_add(conn, cursor, species_id, latin, abbrev):
    sql = "INSERT INTO species VALUE ('{species_id}', '{latin}', '{abbrev}', NULL);"
    
    A=input("Please define a 'species_id', that should be inserted to the database (used in task 5):")
    B=input("Please define a 'latin', that should be inserted to the database (used in task 5):")
    C=input("Please define a 'abbrev', that should be inserted to the database (used in task 5):")
    
    cursor.execute(sql,[A], [B], [C])
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

EDIT - updated based on feedback

```
def data_add(conn, cursor, species_id, latin, abbrev):
    species_id = input("Please define a 'species_id':")
    latin      = input("Please define a 'latin':")
    abbrev     = input("Please define a 'abbrev':")

    sql = "insert into species(species_id, latin, abbrev) value (?, ?, ?);"
    cursor.execute(sql, (species_id, latin, abbrev));
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgres...?

Comment: Updated that information

Comment: Sqlite and mysql are two different database products with different sql syntax. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use!

Comment: I'm using sqlite3, but there was no use tag. However, the sqlite tag exists, so I added it.

Comment: Do ypu have any ideas @Shadow

Comment: Sqlite3 is a library in python that connects to an sqlite database. You really should get familiar with terminology otherwise your questions may be misunderstood wasting your and our time as well!

Comment: Sure, that's true. However, now I'm clear about that. Do you have any other input regarding the issue, so we can move this forward (not wasting time)?

Comment: You can see what input I have got and I have responded to that, but none have come with a comment on how to move forward. My problem is that I only wanna change three of these four inputs in the table called "species". I don't wanna change "common". Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem with def data_add(conn, cursor, species_id, latin, abbrev): as suggested by @GMB, is that this generates "TypeError: data_add() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'cursor', 'species_id', 'latin', and 'abbrev'".

Answer (score 0):

In python and SQLite, you would do:

```
species_id = input("Please define a 'species_id':")
latin      = input("Please define a 'latin':")
abbrev     = input("Please define a 'abbrev':")

sql = "insert into species(species_id, latin, abbrev) value (?, ?, ?);"
cursor.execute(sql, (species_id, latin, abbrev));
```

This fixes the SQL syntax, and uses a prepared statement. Note that there is no need to `fetch` an `insert` statement, since it does not return a resultset. There also is no need to assign `null` values to columns that are not given for insert; you can just ignore them.

Comment: This gave: TypeError: data_add() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'cursor', 'species_id', 'latin', and 'abbrev'

Comment: @JohnDoe: there were missing parentheses around the value list. Fixed.

Comment: I still get the same Type-error message. Any idea?

Comment: any ideas on how to continue?

Answer (score 0):

```
def data_add(conn, cursor):
    A=input("Please define a 'species_id', that should be inserted to the database (used in task 5):")
    B=input("Please define a 'latin', that should be inserted to the database (used in task 5):")
    C=input("Please define a 'abbrev', that should be inserted to the database (used in task 5):")
    
    sql = "INSERT INTO species (species_id, latin, abbrev) VALUES ('{species_id}', '{latin}', '{abbrev}', NULL);".format(species_id=A, latin=B, abbrev=C)

    cursor.execute(sql,[A], [B], [C])
    conn.commit()
```

Since your getting species_id, latin, abbrev from raw user input, I don't see a reason to include them as function parameters. Keep an eye on your SQL syntax as well.

Python alone won't provide a way to connect to your database, however. You'll need to use a library like [pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I'm connecting using "import sqlite3", so that might not be a problem.

Comment: Your code gave me the following error: TypeError: data_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cursor'

Comment: Here conn and cursor are your two positional arguments. Those (and only those) need to be passed to the function when it's called. The conn argument would need to be a sqlite3 connection object, and cursor a sqlite3 cursor object. See the [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for details.

Comment: Sure, but I can't execute the function when I have both conn and cursor. Then I get this error message. I simply have to chose one or change the code in a different way.